# Javascript - Pop a value from array, but not at the end of array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have for example this array (each number is singolar, no one duplicate) called pvalue : 1 2 3 15 20 12 14 18 7 8 (sizeof 10).

I need for example to pop the value "15", and after this pvalue should be 1 2 3 20 12 14 18 7 8 (sizeof 9). How can do it?

the pop() function take the value at the end of the array. I don't want this :)
cheers

EDIT

```
for(i=0; i<pvalue.length; i++) {
    if(pvalue[i]==param) {
        ind=i;
        break;
    }
}
pvalue.splice(ind, 1);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice). Example: http://jsbin.com/oteme3:

```
var a, b;

a = [1, 2, 3, 15, 20, 12, 14, 18, 7, 8];
display("a.length before = " + a.length);
b = a.splice(3, 1);
display("a.length after = " + a.length);
display("b[0] = " + b[0]);
```

...displays "a.length before = 10", then "a.length after = 9", then "b[0] = 15"

Note that `splice` returns an *array* of the removed values rather than just one, but that's easily handled. It's also convenient for inserting values *into* an array.

Answer (score 11):

To pop the first one off, use:

```
first = array.shift();
```

To pop any other one off, use:

```
removed = array.splice(INDEX, 1)[0];
```