# How to record the select order of a number of checkboxs?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Look at this HTML example:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="myform" action="http://www.mydomain.com/myformhandler.jsp" method="POST">
<div align="center"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="option1" value="Milk"> Milk<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="option2" value="Butter" checked> Butter<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="option3" value="Cheese"> Cheese<br>
<br>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And the resulting output from it:

[image]

I hope to send the ***checked*** checkbox to the servlet, but i also want to  get the ***order*** user selected these checkbox.

For example,user A do stuff like : ***select Cheese,select Butter, select Milk***->then ***Cheese,Butter,Milk*** will be  sent to servlet **with this order**.

If user B do stuff like : ***select Cheese,select Butter, deselect Butter, select Milk , select Butter***->then **Cheese,Milk,Butter** will be  sent to servlet **with this order**.

Appreciate.

Comment: Nothing to do with Java.

Comment: You're going to have to bind the `onclick` event for all the checkboxes and keep track of the order with Javascript, then send it in the form submission as a `<input type="hidden" />`.

Comment: What should happen if the user deselects an option ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a global variable to track the order:

```
var selectOrder = 0;
```

Bind this function to your onclick event in your inputs:

```
function onClickHandler() {
    var senderId = this.id;

    selectOrder = selectOrder + 1;
    document.getElementById(senderId).setAttribute('data-order', selectOrder);
}
```

That will set a data-* (custom) attribute on each one with the order they were checked. So, when you submit your form, you can grab all of the checkboxes and get the order with `.getAttribute('data-order');` **Don't forget** to reset your `selectOrder = 0` when you submit so it will reorder them on the next time through.

Comment: I need to **selectOrder = selectOrder + 1** or **selectOrder = selectOrder - 1**  according to the select or deselect? yes?

Comment: Deselection can make it trickier. You can traverse the DOM and reset them all to be 1,2,3 or you can just reset the deselected one and keep the selectOrder the same, so you may have 1,4,8, but they'll still be ordered correctly when they are sent to the server. If you have to maintain the 1,2,3, you're going to have to do a lot of DOM parsing.

Answer (score 2):

Check the fiddle for the checkbox order [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dLdgJ/3/)

I used the following **JS Code**

```
checkedOrder = []
inputList = document.getElementsByTagName('input')
for(var i=0;i<inputList.length;i++) {
    if(inputList[i].type === 'checkbox') {
        inputList[i].onclick = function() {
            if (this.checked) {
                 checkedOrder.push(this.value)            
            } else {
                 checkedOrder.splice(checkedOrder.indexOf(this.value),1) 
            }
            console.log(checkedOrder)
        }    
    }
}
```

​

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.This works better

```
    <html>
<head>
<title>My Page</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var arr=new Array();
function fnc(myid)
{

    if(document.getElementById(myid).checked == true)
    {
        arr.push(document.getElementById(myid).value);
        alert(arr);
    }
    else
    {
        var item1=document.getElementById(myid).value;
        for(i=0;i<2;i++)
        {
            if(arr[i]=item1)
            {
                found=i;
            arr.splice(found,1);
            }
        }
    }

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="myform" action="http://www.mydomain.com/myformhandler.jsp" method="POST">
<div align="center"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="option1" value="Milk" id="Milk" onchange="fnc(this.id)"> Milk<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="option2" value="Butter" id="Butter" onchange="fnc(this.id)"> Butter<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="option3" value="Cheese" id="Cheese" onchange="fnc(this.id)"> Cheese<br>
<br>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nope, can't  work. array.pop() doesn't take any input. It only removes and returns the last element in the array (highest index) You'd have to use splice. The high-level approach seems fine - the implementation however, is a little more shaky.. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745768/javascript-pop-a-value-from-array-but-not-at-the-end-of-array

Comment: yes you are right. Thanks. I've changed my code and this works fine according to the requirement, I think

Comment: Short and sweet answer though. My ++

Answer (score 1):

Here, give this a try.

It maintains an array of all of the options' values, along with the order in which they were clicked. It handles the case where items are already checked when the page loads, by arbitrarily assigning them an increasing index for the order they were clicked in.

It handles items being unselected, it also can provide you with a little more info as a happy side-effect of the way I've done it. You can for instance get back values of 2, 3, 4 for selection order. If I load the page, then select Milk then cheese before unselecting then reselecting Butter, I get back the values <strike>2,3,4</strike> 2,4,3 - I can straight away tell that the last selection made was Butter, and that it had previously been the first item selected. Likely useless, but an interesting consequence to me all the same.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Page</title>
<style>
#myDiv
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
}
</style>
<script>
window.addEventListener('load', mInit, false);
function mInit()
{
    var i, inputList = document.getElementsByTagName('input'), n = inputList.length;
    var cbCount = 0;
    var curOrder = 0;

    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if (inputList[i].type == 'checkbox')
        {
            cbCount++;
            var cur = inputList[i];
            cur.addEventListener('change', onCbChange, false);
            var mObj = {val:cur.value, selOrder:0};
            if (cur.checked)
            {
                mObj.selOrder = ++curOrder;
            }
            availOptions.push( mObj );
        }
    }
}

var availOptions = [];  // an array to hold objects - { val, selOrder }

function getItem(value)
{
    var i, n = availOptions.length;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if (availOptions[i].val == value)
            return availOptions[i];
    }
    return null;
}

// just clear it's selOrder member
function mUnselect(value)
{
    var Item = getItem(value);
    Item.selOrder = 0;
}

// iterate through the list, find the highest value of selOrder, increment it and set this item's selOrder to that
function mSelect(value)
{
    var i, n = availOptions.length;
    var curMax=0;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if (availOptions[i].selOrder > curMax)
            curMax = availOptions[i].selOrder;
    }
    curMax++;
    getItem(value).selOrder = curMax;
}

function onCbChange()
{
    if (this.checked)
        mSelect(this.value);
    else
        mUnselect(this.value);
    alert(this.value + ': ' + this.checked);
}

function showCurState()
{
    var i, n=availOptions.length;
    var mStr = '';
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        mStr += availOptions[i].val + ", selOrder: " + availOptions[i].selOrder + "\n"
    alert(mStr);
}

</script>


</head>
<body>
<div id='myDiv' align="left">
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="option1" value="Milk"> Milk<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="option2" value="Butter" checked> Butter<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="option3" value="Cheese"> Cheese<br>
<br>
<input type='button' onclick='showCurState();' value='Show state'/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```